# Ubuntu 15.10 borked my Nvidia Optimus xorg setup

Tags: nvidia-optimus, 15.10

I had a fiddly but working setup for my nvidia/intel driver setup where by I used the nouveau drivers and had the intel driver disabled,  it gets hot but it works.

I just upgraded to 15.10 and no I cant login at all , It would no enter failsafe mode.

I had to ssh to the laptop and edit xorg.conf and while I was editing it something in the boot was editing it at the same time.  I set the drivers for both devices to vesa and saved on top of whatever Ubuntu boot changes were doing.

I dont have nvidia drivers installed.  but no lsmod tells me i have i915 drivers running which is odd since I have Driver "vesa"  in xorg.

!st question does 15.10 still use xorg as before or has something fundamentally changed?

sencond any idea why a failing boot rewrites xorgs.conf.

Any idea for what to try?  I tried to reconfivute nouveau-firmware but afte a fresh upgrade presumably everything has just been reconfigured?

Comment: Even after a  successful boot with the Driver "vesa" trick, if I reboot it rewrites my working xorg.conf during boot!  So I have to SSH from another machine and hit :w! in vi a few times till it loads.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it seems 15.10 upgrade re-installed bumblebee perhaps other things which are no longer needed (breaks things) for my nvidia optimus setup.

I now have

- no nvidia packages
- xserver-xorg-video-nouveau drivers installed (cant be removed anyway)
- no nvidia-prime (via aptitude purge)
- no bumblebee    (via aptitude purge)
- no xorg.conf at all, which is a bit strange

This boots and I can see each graphics card is working, test with

```
DRI_PRIME=0 glxgears
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears
```

You can see that the nvidia card has rendering issues, but the Intel one works ok.

Its pretty crashy, seems sleep breaks more regularly and the system freezes every now and again, but it turns on.

An I have that warm feeling you get from using open source drivers. :)

Moral of the story is don't buy hardware with nvidia optimus.

N.B. Don't trust the information in Ubuntu's  Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab.  I don't know where that info comes from or how it configures the system but it breaks things with Optimus.  You loose the whole desktop if something goes wrong with graphics drivers so a GUI on configuring graphics drivers is a silly idea!  I used aptitude/dpkg and deleted a few files relaveted to nvidia and bumblebee that aptitude purge had missed.